# Would it be possible to set up a security system like the one in jurassic park?

Tags: python, security

Would it be possible to set up a security system like the one in jurassic park (the book) using raspberry pi's? If so, how much time would it take, and how much would it cost? Using python as the language.

(I'm not 100% sure this is the right site to ask this question. If so, please direct/migrate me to the correct one so I can ask it there)

Comment: "... like the one in Jurassic Park..." You mean the one that failed? :)       But seriously, I'm 100% sure this isn't the right site for your question (that said, **someone will answer** :). You may get some enlightening comments, but your question is "opinion-based". Maybe [read this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/asking)

Comment: *"please direct/migrate me to the correct one"* -> https://www.reddit.com/r/raspberry_pi/

Comment: @Seamus I have... How is it opinion based?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/

Comment: Aah. I think I see what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Question***

> Is it possible to use Rpi and python to build a Jurassic Park security
>   system?

***Answer***

*Yes, I guess we would need 1,000 Rpi4, and 2,000 sensors and actuators.  But python is not enough, we need other languages like NodeRed which is more suitable for event driven, and web design etc.*

> Perhaps the OP can propose a scaled down version with 2 cages and 4
>   baby dinosaurs.

[image: j park s system]